# How to write a script that runs whenever a new file is added to a specific directory?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, script

I've never written a script for OS X, and I don't really know which scripting tool i'll use for this task.

Here's a pseudo code for the script I want to build :

```
whenever a new file X is added to the directory D do:
copy X 
paste X to the directory B
```

I don't want someone to code this for me, I want to know what tool (language maybe) should I use to write this script, and how to make OS X runs it whenever the event occurs.

I don't know what to tag this. Please contribute.
Please redirect if this isn't the right forum for this question.

Comment: I'd say try using AppleScript first

Comment: Folder actions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple using Automator & Folder Actions.

- Make a new Folder Action, then set the source to Folder A
- select a Finder action from the left column,
- drag 'Copy Finder Items' from the centre to the right
- set the destination to Folder B.
- Give it a name & save.

[image]

Every time anything is added to A it will automatically copy to B.

Comment: And if you want to do something more complicated, Automator has a 'Run Shell Script' action which you can use with a number of shell script variations, Ruby, Perl, and Python. If you go down this route, I'd advocate sticking with sh/bash or whichever language with which you are most comfortable.

Comment: I've found there to be a bug in this simple Automator Action in that if a file already exists in A and you answer Replace, it doesn't get copied to B.  This was tested under OS X 10.8.5 and might not be an issue in other versions of OS X.

Comment: Thanks! I had to also right click on the folder in the Finder and click "Folder Actions Setup" > "Run Service" > add the action to the folder there. (macOS 11.6)

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of two ways that require (free) third party packages:

1st. A package called [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) por monitoring file system events and triggering actions. It's actually a python package, but it also includes a shell utility so you can create scripts from the terminal without actually coding.

2nd. use a small program called [fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch/wiki/How-to-Use-fswatch) which uses Mac OS's File System Events API to monitor your files and folders, and can trigger scripts.

They both require you installing the package/program, and seem to do what you require. Hope this at least points you in the right direction.